# Does the Couchbase Spark Connector having support for PySpark?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, couchbase, apache-spark-sql

We have 10 nodes AWS EMR Cluster with emr 5.5.0 version, Spark 2.1.0

We want to write summary data into couchbase database. We are using PySpark with Spark SQL to generate summary data. Summary data is, in the form of PySpark DataFrame.

We want to write this summary data(PySpark DataFrame) into couchbase database.

Does the Couchbase Spark Connector having support for PySpark? If yes, could you please share the information on how to write data into couchbase database using PySpark.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, Couchbase does not have support for PySpark.